# Polymer dynamic element template

Tags: javascript, polymer, marionette

I'm using Polymer with MarionetteJS and the issue that I'm having is detailed below:

```
var ItemTemplate = `
    <paper-icon-button icon="close"></paper-icon-button>
`;

var Item = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "paper-icon-item",
    template: _.template(ItemTemplate),
});
```

As you can see from the code above, I am expecting that:

```
var item = new Item()
item.render();
```

would result in something like:

```
<paper-icon-item>
    <paper-icon-button icon="close"></paper-icon-button>
</paper-icon-item>
```

but what I am getting is the following:

```
<paper-icon-item role="option" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" class="x-scope paper-icon-item-0">
    <div id="contentIcon" class="content-icon style-scope paper-icon-item"></div>
</paper-icon-item>
```

I've nailed this down to the fact that the "content" doesn't exist when the element distributes it. I am looking for a way to have the content re-distributed when the template has been rendered.

I have tried to "distributeContent":

```
var Item = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "paper-icon-item",
    template: _.template(ItemTemplate),

    onRender: function() {
        this.el.distributeContent();
    },
});
```

But this doesn't work at all.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting I have found that you need to use the Polymer DOM Api to manipulate the html that gets added:

```
var ItemTemplate = `
    <paper-icon-button icon="close"></paper-icon-button>
`;

var Item = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "paper-icon-item",
    template: _.template(ItemTemplate),
    // This is where the "magic" happens
    attachElContent: function(html) {
        Polymer.dom(this.el).innerHTML = html;
        return this;
    },
});
```